# Android Creating Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to use the code google implemented but it seems I'm missing something. Here's the code

```
int notificationId = 001;
// Build intent for notification content
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ViewEventActivity.class);
viewIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_ID, eventId);
PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventLocation)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

When I run this, i see that my device obtains the notification, but my ViewEventActivity class is not activated when i click to the notification. I tried to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to my viewIntent (it was a tip in the definition of getActivity() method) but no luck there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i missed the declaration of my activity ViewEventActivity in manifest.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ViewEventActivity" />
```

It's odd that application did not crash when the reference ViewEventActivity.class was not found.

Comment: Intents are a lot like request messages. The notification service sent out a message requesting ViewEventActivity to be run, but the system didn't deliver it to your app because your app didn't list it as one that it cared about.